# Einstein's summation convention and double indices

Tags: summation, notation

So I'm actually rather familiar with Einstein' summation notation and I understand objects like $a^{\mu \nu} a_{\mu \nu}$ just fine.

But now I'm suddenly wondering why I've never come across objects like this: $a^{\mu \nu} a_{\mu \nu} b^{\mu \nu}$. Is there a notation reason for this or do these objects just not come up? From what I can see,

$$a^{\mu \nu} a_{\mu \nu} b^{\mu \nu} = a^{0 0} a_{00} b^{0 0} + a^{1 0} a_{1 0} b^{1 0} +...$$
And so on for all permutations and indices. Is this a valid way of using Einstein's summation convention? Can one basically treat $a^{\mu \nu} b^{\mu \nu}$ as an object $c^{\mu \nu}$ with upper indices?

Comment: how do u decide if u contract a with b or a with a? i don't think einstein convention makes sense here

Comment: The question I have about this is the same I asked below: Would it make a difference? The remaining object should share the index and should thus go along with the summation. At least that's what intuition tells me, I'd like to hear why it wouldn't. If $k=0,1$ and I want to look at an object like $a^k a_k b^k$ why is this not $a^0a_0b^0+a^1a_1b^1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These object are used very rarely. As I know no common summation rule is valid for that. So your interpretation of the Einstein summation over more than two indicies is not correct. So I used the summation sign ahead then.

But in most cases $a_\mu b^\mu$ are used because of a Linear form where they come up with.

As far as I know terms ala $a^{\mu \nu} a_{\mu \nu} b^{\mu \nu}$ are only correct, if the symbols of $\mu, \nu$ defined before. For example: $$c^{\mu\nu}=a^{\mu \nu} a_{\mu \nu} b^{\mu \nu}$$

Comment: Can you explain what part of the convention forbids this kind of object? From what I can tell $a_\mu b^\mu$ would be a summation and if I look at $a^\mu a_\mu b^\mu$ the remaining $a^\mu$ would just be an indexed object following along with that summation, as I look at each index individually. The remaining object should be a scalar. So I am not sure how it could be wrong.

Comment: $a^\mu a_\mu b^\mu$ why is there a $a^\mu$ remaining? And not the $b^\mu$ ? There is no common convention for terms like that.

Comment: Would it make a difference? The remaining object shares the index and should thus go along with the summation. At least that's what intuition tells me, I'd like to hear why it wouldn't. If $k=0,1$ and I want to look at an object like $a^k a_k b^k$ why is this not $a^0a_0b^0+a^1a_1b^1$?

Comment: Because of convention. If you mean this than write $\sum_k a^k a_k b^k
$ Then everyone know what is going on. Maybe Einstein forgot these cases.

Comment: Yes, see because that would obviously work, I figured the other notation would directly imply that I mean this. I guess it doesn't, then? Thanks.